# Kill process by name and owner?

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, kill

Before I look into reinventing the wheel and roll my own, is anyone aware of an application/utility that allows me to kill processes, filtering by both process name *and* process owner? Alternatively could this be done through powershell? (My powershell-fu is sadly lacking).

I've looked at both `pskill` and `taskkill`. Although `pskill` allows terminating by process name, it doesn't allow me to further filter by process owner. I've also looked at WMI via wmic (`wmic process`), but the WMI interface doesn't return the process owner (at least from what I can tell), so can't use this either.

***Rationale***
I do a chunk of development on Windows. Some of this involves dealing with Component Services (COM+). COM+ has a generic host process - dllhost.exe - that's used both for custom (i.e., stuff I've developed) elements and system processes. I can differentiate them by the owner they run as. So, for example, I want to kill all the dllhost.exe processes owned by me, but ignore the ones owned by SYSTEM.

This would save me going in to Task Manager on a regular basis and identifying and manually killing each one :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In powershell you would do:

```
gwmi -query "select * from win32_process where name='PROCESSNAME.exe'" | %{if($_.GetOwner().User -eq 'USERNAME'){$_.terminate()}}
```

Comment: Ah -- excellent cheers. That works nicely :-)

Answer (score 24):

You weren't looking hard enough.

```
taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq foo.exe" /fi "username eq Chris"
```

You can even filter by modules loaded, using `/fi "modules eq libfoo.dll"`.

Comment: Much easier than the PS method :)

Comment: You're right -- I wasn't looking hard enough. That's bad of me.