# Kill process belonging to a different user from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line

There are a a couple of ways to kill a process from the command prompt when running in Administrator mode:

- taskkill /IM "ProcessToKill.exe" /F
- PowerShell Stop-Process -Name "ProcessToKill.exe" -Force

But if the command prompt is not Administrator, you get an "Access is denied" error.

Can you force a target process to be killed regardless of how the script is launched (double-click, right-click "Run as administrator", etc.)?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/109010/kill-a-process-which-says-access-denied

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/374999/kill-process-by-name-and-owner

Comment: The linked answer provided a solution: `wmic process where name='ProcessToKill.exe' delete`